# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation with VS2010 and Gallio

Tags: c#, gallio

I'm building a C# project with VS2010 and .Net 4.01. Every thing builds fine but when I run the unit tests using MSTest I get "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" for every test run. I found a posting about Gallio causing this issue, but it did not have a solution. 
If uninstall Gallio the problem goes away. But I'm building several projects on the same build machine and one of those projects requires Gallio, so i need to install it again.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Read the inner exception.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm running this on the command line.

Comment: Anyone else have any idea on this??

Comment: @SLaks When I got "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" in VS2010 it was in a plain messagebox popup with no detail of any kind. If there is a way to see the inner exception I'd also like to know

Comment: @James: Attach a debugger to VS and set Break On All Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I've read of many fixes which weren't of any help (deleting suo, deleting bin & obj, deleting test results).

I scanned through the project files for things which looked wrong. For me it was fixed by changing a reference to the wrong framework. Using `<Reference Include="System.Core" />` in MyAppTest.csproj instead of:

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Strangely, git showed it had been working with this reference since I first created the project and there were not recent reference changes other than adding an image as an embedded resource.

Edit: Turns out this error is more temperamental than I thought. It came back and checking out a previous commit doesn't fix it even after cleaning builds and test cases.